# Increasing understanding of Python argument variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the following Python script named ex13.py:

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print("The script is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

I have a question about the following line of code:

```
 script, first, second, third = argv
```

We are saying assign `argv` to four variables on the left in this order.

Then when I, use this script in my terminal:

```
python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd
```

I understand that we are passing variables to a script using the terminal as an input method. However what's confusing me is this.

When I was writing basic Python scripts the way I would call them is with:

```
python ex3.py
```

Am I correct in saying that this `python ex3.py` is not passing a single command line argument and `python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd` is passing several?

Comment: you are correct. keep in mind though that `argv[0]` will contain the name of the script regardless of how many parameters you passed it

Comment: @Nullman he is NOT correct - as you mention youself, `python ex3.py` is passing the argument 'ex3.py'.

Answer (score 1):

When working from the command line, argv returns a list of the command line arguments, where the first (at place zero `argv[0]` we get the python file name that was used after the `pyhton` name).

from place one and up, the values are related to the order in which arguments was recieved. take note that if you use optional arguments (`python myscript.py -p 127.0.0.1`) those are counted in argv too. so you will get `argv[1] == -p`

> Am I correct in saying that this `python ex3.py` is not passing a single
>   command line argument and `python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd` is passing
>   several?

no, you are incorrect, `python ex3.py` is passing 1 argument, `argv[0] = ex3.py`.